# How to add role hierarchy in discord.User cog?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a ban command which uses discord.User cog as to ban members who are not in the guild, but I want to add role hierarchy but when I checked the docs there was no attribute for it, is there a way to do both? Have role hierarchy and be able to ban users who are not in the guild

Comment: you can ban Users that are not in the Guild, see [`discord.Guild.ban`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.ban) in the docs ; what do you mean with 'add role hierarchy'? Can you give us some examples or things you already tried?

Comment: I meant like moderators not using the command against each other, although the command doesn't ban them it messages them which is something I want to remove. I am using discord.guild.ban btw

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the roles of the user and check if he has a role in a list. I prefer to use the role IDs since it can't be changed.

Use [`typing.Union`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#typing-union) to either get a member, or the id if the user is not in the server

```py
from typing import Union

@client.command()
@commands.bot_has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, user: Union[discord.Member, int]):
    if isinstance(user, int):
        # user is not in guild -> ban him by id
        pass
    else:
        whitelisted_roles = [123456, 456789, 789012] # List of Mod roles 
        for role in user.roles:
            if role.id in whitelisted_roles:
                return await ctx.send("You can't ban this user! He is a moderator!")
        else:
            pass
            # ban the member
```

Comment: How can I do it without whitelisting roles? more like it checks permission of the user and if its true it won't ban

Comment: try `if user.guild_permissions.ban_members:
    return await ctx.send("you cannot ban a staff member")` instead of iterate through the roles

Comment: He wants role heirarchy, he doesn't want someone to be banned if the person is higher than the user running this command.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOwerflow!

Yes, it's possible to check role hierarchy as well as ban users with their `user_id`s.

I recommend taking a looking into the answer by [Guddi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68163999/11697614).

First and formost:

- You need a check role heirarchy.
- To do that, here's the code:

```py
if not (user.guild_permissions.administrator and user.top_role.position > ctx.me.top_role.position and user.top_role.position > ctx.author.top_role.position):
   user.ban()
```

To ban the user who is not in the guild,

```
if isinstance(user, int):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(user)
    await ctx.guild.ban(user)
```

I hope this is helpful.